# Why doesn't my server render my website properly?

Tags: hosting, javascript, html5

I want to know what could be wrong with my server?
I have uploaded the exact same website files to both a public and private server and it doesn't display the same way on both of them.

The files have been uploaded onto a public web host and it functions perfectly on:

http://www.singingnetwork.com

The exact same files have been uploaded onto my private server on:

http://www.graphicdesignmontreal.ca

On this private server, the font is not displaying the way it's supposed to and the JavaScript affects are not functioning properly either.

The site files use HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript

Comment: Being pedantic: Not your server renders the page it is your browser.

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong with your /js folder in the http://www.graphicdesignmontreal.ca site.

Thats why is not working right. I suggest using Firebug, then you can see whats wrong right there.

Comment: Yes, if you request the js files directly you get an "Internal Server Error". I'm not sure how Firebug is going to help with this? A side issue... you appear to have the Google Analytics code in the page twice?

Comment: Ok in reality this is my friends private server and only he has access to the server logs. I will try and retrieve them or try and get him to resolve this.

And yes, thanks for catching that I have two analytics installed. I will remove one of them.

Answer (score 4):

Your `/js` folder and files under it are serving a 500 error (internal server error). Check your web server logs, they should tell you what's wrong.